# grails jms start listening after apllication is completly launched

Tags: grails, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using grails `jms-1.3`plugin and I have the problem, that my jms listener Service starts consuming messages from activeMQ before the application is fully up and running. This results in an error when I try to write some messages to the DB.
So my question is, how can I manage to start consuming from a queue manually. So that I can set autoStartup to false.

here is my example grails code:

**ConsumerService.groovy**

```
package jmsstartstop

import grails.plugin.jms.Queue

class ConsumerService {
    static exposes = ["jms"]
    @Queue(name="liesMich")
    def receiveMessage(String msg) {
        log.info("Received Message:" + msg)
    }
}
```

**resources.groovy**

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory

beans = {
    jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
        targetConnectionFactory = { ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf ->
            brokerURL = grailsApplication.config.jms.brokerURL
        }
    }
}
```

**Config.groovy**

```
jms{
    brokerURL='tcp://localhost:61616'
    containers {
        standard {
            autoStartup = false
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is something like `jmsConnectionFactory.getTargetConnectionFactory().start()` that can be called in `Bootstrap.groovy` or maybe in a controller manually. But unfortunately this start method does not exist in the TargetConnectionFactory.

Is there a way to do it, or any other suggestions?

**Bootstrap.groovy** (which is not working)

```
class BootStrap {
    def jmsConnectionFactory

    def init = { servletContext ->
        jmsConnectionFactory.??WHATEVER??.start()

    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be fixed in the latest SNAPSHOT (See: https://github.com/gpc/jms/commit/dee0630d0073d9611da3d0a0efbf8b8b33565ccd) Try using `:jms:1.3-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Your right, thanks for this hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the plugin starts processing messages before the Datasource plugin (part of Grails) has finished it's own startup.

The good news is that this [appears to be fixed](https://github.com/gpc/jms/commit/dee0630d0073d9611da3d0a0efbf8b8b33565ccd) in the latest SNAPSHOT version of the plugin.

To use the SNAPSHOT change your plugin as such: `:jms:1.3-SNAPSHOT` in your `BuildConfig.groovy`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to MANUALLY start the JMSListener services on Bootstrap file:

e.g.

```
In listener.groovy:
class ClientListenerService {

    boolean transactional = true
    static exposes = ["jms"]
    static destination = "com.moviesxd.api.domain.Client_QUEUE"
    static isTopic = false
    static container = "manualStart"


In bootstrap.groovy:

def clientRequestListenerJmsListenerContainer

...

clientRequestListenerJmsListenerContainer.start()
```

This solves the problem.